# Toggling Google Chrome extension popout

Tags: google-chrome-extension, toggle

I have made a Google Chrome extension which mimics the Internet Explorer favorites drop-down.

However, the thing that's bugging me is that I click the icon and the popout is displayed, but if I click the icon again it reloads my popout instead of closing like I want it to.

How can I set the extension popout to toggle being opened and closed on the icon click instead of always being opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control this as it is handled by Chrome. I recall hearing that some platforms (maybe windows) would close the popup when the browserAction button is clicked so it may be something you can open an issue on http://crbug.com to have it be consistant.